# How to onClick in map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I map elements, and put onClick button, that takes choosen element, and make needed actions with it. problem is how to make onClick={function} to know which element is selected? Because its always take last map element (English grammar is not my strong side).

```
<div className={styles.list}>
      {users.map(u => (
          <div onClick={handleClick}}> // this is function that picks element
          <UserItem
              key={u.id}
              user={u}
          /> </div>
      ))}
  </div>
```

Comment: Probably you can pass `u.id` to `handleClick` function so the function will be aware of which `<UserItem>` component was clicked. Think about it like `onClick={(e) => handeClick(u.id)}`.

Comment: Or pass The actual user object to The function. `onClick={() => handleClick(u) }`

Comment: Wouldn't you need to call it as a function handleClick() ?  you can then pass object u to it. handleClick(u) or any of it's property.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should pass the u.id to the handleClick function.

```
<div className={styles.list}>
    {users.map(u => (
       <div onClick={() => handleClick(u.id)}>
           ...
       </div>
    ))}
</di>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the `u` variable that represents a single user like so:

```
<div className={styles.list}>
  {users.map(u => (
  <div onClick={() => this.handleClick(u)}> // this is function that picks element
  <UserItem
      key={u.id}
      user={u}
  /> </div>
))}
```

Read up in their [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-an-event-handler-or-callback).

Answer (score 0):

Your handler should look like this.

```js
const handleClick = (user) => () => {
  // do whatever you want with the clicked user here.
}
```

And you should pass your `user` like so.

```js
<div className={styles.list}>
  {users.map(u => (
    <div onClick={handleClick(u)}}> // this is function that picks element
      <UserItem
        key={u.id}
        user={u}
      /> 
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

That's your solution but please don't rest there, search more for [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) because you'll work with them a lot in your React projects.